# RTS/CTS simultenous transmission of RTS frame

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I'd like to know what happens if the RTS frame will be transfered by two devices (which cannot hear one another) in the same time. So it's like a classical hidden terminal problem - A and C are not able to see each other and want to transmit to B. I know that RTS/CTS reduces the collision problem so is it one possibility when the collision will appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collision happens when two devices transmit at the same time, so, yes, a collision occurs, even if the two sending devices cannot detect the collision. It is, after all, CSMA/*CA* (for *Collision Avoidance*). The WAP will dtect the collision, and it will not send CTS to either requesting host. Both hosts will try again, later.